Cannot import strings from library without using all path on Image picker?
I am using a library to pick images from gallery
 implementation("com.github.esafirm:android-image-picker:3.0.0")

the problem is when i try to use strings from it, I cant import them without using all the path for it, like this:
folderTitle = com.esafirm.imagepicker.R.string.ef_title_folder.toString()
        imageTitle = com.esafirm.imagepicker.R.string.ef_title_select_image.asString()

It should let me import them like this :
imageTitle = R.string.ef_title_select_image.asString()

I think the problem is because I use images of project, and then maybe the R thinks that the import is for R of project.
How to fix this issue?


I think the problem is because I use images of project, and then maybe the R thinks that the import is for R of project.

Indeed that's what it does, you can't exactly change that but what you can do is add an import alias on top like:
import com.esafirm.imagepicker.R as ImgR

and then use it like the following:
imageTitle = ImgR.string.ef_title_select_image.asString()


but I also have a case like this:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert)
}

the R.style does not find the theme if i dont use package path before, even though in this fragment i don't have nothing else, I just created it, and also I have imported the appcompat on gradle

That's weird, might be something wrong with your gradle or project config. Check if your XML files are fine, and the package is same as the one you want to import.

Yes the XML file and package name is fine but i don't understand why this is still happening
